# CentOS 5 Python - How To Force Specific Version?

Tags: python, centos, version

I have a python program that I'm trying to run, my fresh install of CentOS came with 2.4.3 of Python, but I just manually installed 2.7. My install is located at /usr/local/bin/python2.7, so its all there, but when I do

```
python -V
```

it comes back with 2.4.3. How would I force 2.7 (the latest) to be the main and only python as my program requires 2.6 or higher?

Thanks

Comment: This might be more of a CentOS/Linux administration question than a programming one. You need the `/usr/bin/python` symlink to point to `python2.7`, or you need PATH to have such a symlink before the 2.4 one. You can either do that manually (sitewide or in your `.bashrc` or similar configuration file) or see if there's a version selecting utility on CentOS. (Similar to `python_select` on MacPorts.)

Comment: @millimoose: it is a bad idea to change /usr/bin/python. Applications that do not expect this might break.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, I guess a better solution would be using `virtualenv` instead of relying on the OS environment to be set up right.

Answer (score 3):

To run your script using python2.7, you could change the shebang line in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Make sure `python2.7` is in your `PATH` in this case.

To point other tools such as `easy_install`, `pip` to python2.7, you could use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). Create virtualenv for python2.7 and activate it in `.bash_profile` to make it default. See [this answer about easy way to install virtualenv, easy_install, pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946537/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out your default python executable is 2.4.3, you need to either directly reference the 2.7 like so

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

or by replacing your python link to point to the new interpreter.

To check your running the right interpreter in your scripts you can do something like this;

```
assert platform.python_version_tuple()[:2] == ('2', '7')
```

Is a pretty common idonim

If you want to accept any version above 2.7 then do this

```
major, minor, _ = platform.python_version_tuple()
assert (int(major) >= 2) or ((int(major) == 2) and (int(major) >=7))
```